# Zero probability of dead-end in a three-dimensional self-avoiding random walk?

Tags: java, arrays

This is Sedgewick & Wayne exercise 1.4.35.

Run experiments to **verify** that the dead-end probability is 0 for a three-dimensional self-avoiding walk.

[image]

And here is my program:

```
public class test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int trials = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int deadEnds = 0;
        for (int t = 1; t <= trials; t++)
        {
            boolean[][][] a = new boolean[n][n][n];
            int x = n/2, y = n/2, z = n/2;
            while (x > 0 && x < n-1 && y > 0 && y < n-1 && z > 0 && z < n-1)
            {
                a[x][y][z] = true;
                if (a[x+1][y][z] && a[x-1][y][z] && a[x][y+1][z] && a[x][y-1][z] && 
                    a[x][y][z+1] && a[x][y][z-1])
                {
                    deadEnds++;
                    break;
                }
                double r = Math.random();
                if      (r < 1.0/6) {if (!a[x+1][y][z]) x++;}
                else if (r < 2.0/6) {if (!a[x-1][y][z]) x--;}
                else if (r < 3.0/6) {if (!a[x][y+1][z]) y++;}
                else if (r < 4.0/6) {if (!a[x][y-1][z]) y--;}
                else if (r < 5.0/6) {if (!a[x][y][z+1]) z++;}
                else if (r < 1.000) {if (!a[x][y][z-1]) z--;}
            }
        }
        System.out.println((100.0*deadEnds)/trials + "% dead ends.");
    }
}
```

My problem is that I do not get the probability 0 even for a 100-by-100-by-100 lattice. Is there any problem with my program that I am not able to see?

**Here's the text verifying the above-mentioned claim in the exercise:**

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The dead-end probability is *not* zero.

Comment: The only "Sedgewick 1.4.33" exercises I've been able to identify don't look like this.

Comment: I'm using the book "Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach" by Sedgewick and Wayne.

Comment: 1.4.33 in that book appears to be an exercise about finding duplicates in an array.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake. I meant 1.4.35.

Comment: 1.4.35 in that book doesn't seem to contain any assertion about the dead-end probability. Maybe it's an edition difference, and they changed it because it was wrong?

Comment: Maybe but in the page 115 of the text, the author claims the same thing!

Comment: I can't tell which page is page 115 in the Google Books copy I'm looking at, but in the discussion about self-avoiding random walks, the text actually says that a dead end is *near-certain* in a large grid.

Comment: That is right but for the 2D version as the author claims. And the program for that predicts it correctly.

Comment: Maybe I should email them about this.

Comment: Well, whatever the book says, the dead-end probability is definitely not 0. I don't know whether you're reading the book wrong or whether the book is wrong, but the thing you're trying to verify is absolutely wrong.

Comment: I can add a picture of it.

Comment: "Virtually certain to escape" just means the dead-end probability is low, not that it's zero. Also, it's only true for small enough grids. Make a 3D grid large enough, and dead-end probability approaches 1 again.

Comment: The 1.4.35 image is definitely making a false claim, though. That's not what 1.4.35 looks like in the copy I'm looking at. They probably changed it in later editions.